# IIS Log files for ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I am testing ASP.NET website and for that I have turned logging on at IIS6.0.

Following are the observations during testing:

1. Each link, png image, MS Chart and CSS file has been requested separately, one after another.
2. For request of say login page it is taking around 30-45 seconds to complete and in that page only 6 images are there and at log file it is observed that there are separate requests for each images one after another.

Can anybody help me to improve site performance and also I would like to know that is it possible that all requests would send to server parallel?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to improve on the app speed by parallelizing the downloads !

I recommend going through `google page-speed` and `yahoo's yslow`, and read the practices that they propose. I felt it informative.

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/

http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/help/index.html

Thanks

Comment: Highly agree. Also recommend Steve Souders' "High Performance Websites " book: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529307

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have you checked web-site `Performance` tab? Limits could've been set there. Also check that keep-alives are enabled (`web site` tab).

Then you should profile your server using [System Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/86afd5ee-e183-4a5a-91fd-cf795289c34f.mspx?mfr=true).

If everything mentioned is ok, you should check client side and what's between client and server.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the browser makes HTTP requests to the server for each object it finds on the page.  You can eliminate those requests, or reduce how often they happen, by enabling client-side caching.  For static files, you can configure that in IIS.

You can parallelize requests for images (not JS files) by assigning them to different domains; if they are all in a single domain, the browser will request only two at a time.

However, you question opens the door to a big subject.  In an attempt to provide a detailed answer, I ended up writing a book on the subject, called [Ultra-Fast ASP.NET](http://tinyurl.com/89lf5xm).  I cover the answer to the question from the OP in great detail in Chapter 2.

Comment: Thanks, Rick,
Definetly I will go through with book, Could also help me know about webparts with Oracle 10g and their performance?

Comment: Although I don't cover web parts or Oracle specifically, many of the performance principles that I go over would definitely apply for them as well.